# I have followed the entire procedure correctly to install Apache Tomcat but I'm getting error Access Denied

Tags: apache2, tomcat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmkaC.png)[403 Access Denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jClPM.png)
This is the error I am facing when I try to run my Apache Tomcat Server in localhost:8080
I have edited the roles and users correctly also there's no change I need to do in context.xml but still I can't open the server
I am not getting access to host-manager-webapp only, I have cces to manager-webapp
Please guide me how can I resolve the issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.